# In database for one user transactions are required?

Tags: c#, transactions

I have desktop application and the database on desktop too (sqlite).  I have all validations I the application. Transactions are required in this case?

Thanks

Comment: that depends if some data changes are inter-dependent - i.e. should be done "all or none"... if so the transactions are a good thing even with just one user...

Comment: if only one row is changed at any given time and the data before and after the change is consistent then IMO there would be no need for *explicit transactions* - since the DB usually handles each statement in by itself within its own *implicit transaction*. NOT sure whether this is true for SQLite too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are useful to ensure that every part between `begin transaction` and `commit` have to run without an error. If a error occurs the whole query has no effect.

This has nothing to do with `validation`. You can get errors like timeouts.

> All the work in the transaction is treated as a single unit. Either it is all performed or none of it is. Consistent means that a completed transaction leaves the database in a consistent internal state.

You can find more information on [SQL Team - Introduction to Transactions](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions)

Answer (score 1):

Transactions serve multiple purposes; even with a single user *isolation* can still be a concern if the application is multi-threaded or uses multiple connections for that single user, but perhaps more importantly: it provides *atomicity* of the update for integrity purposes. This is useful when a power-cut happens in the middle of a big update, or something else goes wrong.